# How to make the authentication info available in a springboot websocket request?

Tags: spring-boot, websocket, spring-boot-security

When processing a websocket request in a controller

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()
```

returns null. But I need to know which user is making the request.

What was tried so far:

- Google pointed me towards solutions implementing ChannelInterceptor,
  but in all its methods **getAuthentication()** also returns null. So
  there is nothing to carry over somehow. [How to retrieve the current logged in user in a websocket controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70111595/how-to-retrieve-the-current-logged-in-user-in-a-websocket-controller)
- In an implementation of **onApplicationEvent(SessionSubscribeEvent)**
  or **onApplicationEvent(SessionConnectEvent)** on the websocket
  controller the getAuthentication() returns null.
- I found that in an implementation of HandshakeInterceptor the
  **getAuthentication()** returns a Principal. What can that information be made available in an STOMP Websocket controller method? The methods do not have access to a thread bound request. (*No thread-bound request found* exception) when using:

  *RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes().getSessionId()*

  And the sessionId that can be injected (8 characters) does not match the session id of the normal requests (32 characters): [How to get Session Id in Spring WebSocketStompClient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42243543/how-to-get-session-id-in-spring-websocketstompclient)

  *@Header("simpSessionId") String sessionId*

Answer (score 0):

The controller can listen to SessionConnectEvents and SessionDisconnectEvents which contains the 8 character sessionId:

```
    @EventListener
    public void handleWebSocketConnectListener(SessionConnectEvent event) {
        String sessionId = event.getMessage().getHeaders().get("simpSessionId", String.class);
        Principal principal = event.getUser();
        if (LOG.isInfoEnabled()) LOG.info("Session connect " + sessionId + ": " + principal);
        sessions.put(sessionId, principal);
    }

    @EventListener
    public void handleWebSocketDisconnectListener(SessionDisconnectEvent event) {
        String sessionId = event.getSessionId();
        if (LOG.isInfoEnabled()) LOG.info("Session disconnect " + sessionId);
        sessions.remove(sessionId);
    }
```

And the message handling method can get the 8 character sessionId injected:

```
@MessageMapping("/...")
    public void browserToBackend(Message message, @Header("simpSessionId") String sessionId) throws Exception {
        command.principal = sessions.get(sessionId);
        ...
```